# How to shmget and shmat a double array in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

I know 2D array can be weird in C, and with malloc, i would do something like this:

```
/* This is your 2D array. */
double** matrix;
/* The size dimensions of your 2D array. */
int numRows, numCols;
/* Used as indexes as in matrix[x][y]; */
int x, y; 
/*
 * Get values into numRows and numCols somehow.
 */


/* Allocate pointer memory for the first dimension of a matrix[][]; */
matrix = (double **) malloc(numCols * sizeof(double *));
if(NULL == matrix){free(matrix); printf("Memory allocation failed while allocating for matrix[].\n"); exit(-1);}

/* Allocate integer memory for the second dimension of a matrix[][]; */
for(x = 0; x < numCols; x++)
{
    matrix[x] = (double *) malloc(numRows * sizeof(double));
    if(NULL == matrix[x]){
        free(matrix[x]); printf("Memory allocation failed while allocating for matrix[x][].\n");
         exit(-1);
    }
}
```

and the initialize, with 2 fors, the array.
Now, I want to allocate space in shared memory to a **array, but I don't know if I can do this:

```
shmid2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, numCols * sizeof (int*), IPC_CREAT | 0700);
my_array = (double**) shmat(shmid2, NULL, 0);
```

and then initialize it. Is this correct. If not, how can I do this the right way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Also, `if(NULL == matrix){free(matrix);` is incorrect.

Comment: `free(NULL)` is standardised as a no-op, but you're right it isn't really "correct".

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with a single contiguous shared memory segment.  The trick is that the `double` values themselves live in the shared memory, but your `double *` row pointers can be just regular `malloc` memory, since they're just an index into the shared memory:

```
double *matrix_data;
double **matrix;
int x;

shmid2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, numRows * numCols * sizeof matrix_data[0], IPC_CREAT | 0700);
matrix_data = shmat(shmid2, NULL, 0);

matrix = malloc(numCols * sizeof matrix[0]);
for(x = 0; x < numCols; x++)
{
    matrix[x] = matrix_data + x * numRows;
}
```

(Note that this allocates the index in column-major order, as your code does, which is unusual in C - row-major order is more common).

Separate programs sharing the shared memory segment each allocate their own index `matrix` using `malloc` - only the actual array is shared.

By the way, you can use the same method for a non-shared array, replacing the shared memory call with a plain `malloc()`.  This allows you to use a single allocation for the entire array, plus one for the index, whereas your code has one allocation *per column*.

Comment: And this garantees me that I can access the double pointer like in two fors do something like this : printf("array[i][j] = %d\n",array[i][j])? Because I first tried with a single array, with width*height size, but I find easier and cleaner to have a 2dim array.

Comment: @neverMind: Yes, of course - it is accessed in the same way as your ragged array.

Comment: The problem is that, with my current code, ok I can do that. But each worker then changes the values of my **array, when, in fact, I want to change the array in the shared memory. To access isn't a problem, but to modify it will be, I'll have to do more for's and so :S

Comment: @neverMind: No, the workers will use their own private `double **` as an index into the shared memory.  The shared memory is where the actual `double` values are stored (or equivalent, if you have an array of some other type).  When the workers modify the stored values, they're modifying the shared memory, so the modifications will be seen by the other threads.  An access to `matrix[x][y]` is accessing the shared memory, even though the pointers in `matrix[x]` are not themselves shared.

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it this way, even with malloc because of memory fragmentation once the array becomes big. And with shmget you will get an issue also with fd's (one fd per shmget is used).

I would recommend doing it this way (uncompiled since no C compiler is close)

```
double* matrix = malloc( sizeof(double)*numrows*numcols);

double value = matrix[actrow*numrows+actcol];

free ( matrix);
```

You have to remember numrows throughout your app, but this way it is much more clean from the memory side. Also, now it is one big chunk and you can do the same thing with shmget/shmat.

Comment: Could you exemplify with shmget and shamt. I'm getting a seg fault the way I'm doing ...

Comment: I will try to get my hands on a C compiler later on and will post it!

Comment: thank you so much :) I'm stuck in this point of the code and I know it's because of this. Bah!

Answer (score 0):

I've done it! I will give and example with a struct other then a double array, but you get the point.

So, basically I want to allocate a **pixel, pixel_data (member of structure image_struct, here instantiated as image) in a segment of shared memory.

```
    shmid2 = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, image->width * sizeof (pixel*), IPC_CREAT | 0700);
    image->pixel_data = (pixel**) shmat(shmid2, NULL, 0);

    /* Allocate integer memory for the second dimension of **pixel_data; */
    for (i = 0; i < image->width; i++) {
        shmPixelId = shmget(IPC_PRIVATE, image->height * sizeof (pixel), IPC_CREAT | 0700);
        image->pixel_data[i] = (pixel *) shmat(shmPixelId, NULL, 0);
        if ( image->pixel_data[i]== NULL) {
            shmdt(image->pixel_data[i]);
            printf("Sh_Memory allocation failed while allocating for pixel_data[i][].\n");
            exit(-1);
        }
    }
```

My structures:

```
typedef struct pixel_t {
    byte red;
    byte green;
    byte blue;
}pixel;

typedef struct {
    int width;
    int height;
    pixel **pixel_data;
} image_struct;
```

I follow the same code I did to malloc a dimensional array, but instead I used shared memory.